# How can I disable Spring Tool Suite 3.6.2 dashboard in Eclipse Luna?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to disable automatic start up of the STS dashboard, but I cannot find any option under Window->Preferences->Spring->Dashboard which was present in older versions.

If I close that window it gets opened once again after every Eclipse start. Is there any solution to this? I would prefer solution without re-installing of anything to get deeper insight. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try from menu Window/preferences and then under Spring/Dashboard deselect "Show Dashboard on Startup"

Comment: There is no such option unfortunately. There are "Use old dashboard" and "News feed updates" instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is a Bug [*] in STS 3.6.2 and, as you noticed, it has been fixed in 3.6.3.

There used to be an option to "open the dashboard on startup" which you could disable in the preferences page as some people have suggested above. In 3.6.2 this option is automatically disabled when you close the dashboard, and in keeping with that, the option has been removed from the preference page (since there would be no reason to disable it there as it happens automatically now). The option still exists under the hood but without preference page UI to change it.

Unfortunately there was a bug in the 'disable when closing' functionality which meant it only got disabled if you are using the 'new style' dashboard and not the old style one (I guess this must be the case for you).

> ... I still would like to know some better way.

If you are not happy with simply closing the dashboard once (in STS 3.6.3 or later) then, depending on how you install STS you can opt-out of installing the dashboard.

The easiest way is if you install STS via Eclipse Marketplace. Here's a sequence of steps I just tested to work:

- download Eclipse 4.4.2 distribution (I used Eclipse for Java EE, but probably other ones should work as well)
- Open Marketplace Client (Help >> Eclipse Marketplace).
- Search for "Spring"
- Click the "Install" button on the first "Spring Tool Suite" entry

A dialog should popup allowing you to select the features you want. 
Unselect the entry "Spring Dashboard (optional)".

Then proceed to install the rest.

You should now have an STS installation with everything in it as 'normal', except the dashboard.

[*] = https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3935

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got rid of the dashboard slowing down eclipse start up by updating STS to version 3.6.3. Now when I close it it remains closed next start. But it is not acceptable answer for me because this issue appears often with STS update so I still would like to know some better way.